# Media query does not work with iPhone 4/4S

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

My code is below. My problem is that no matter what I enter in the media query for iPhone 4/4S, it doesn't apply the changes. It just stays exactly as it is. So not adapted to the screen size. I've been trying for an hour now and still no results.

I have been testing with this website: http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('img/tape-measure.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000305;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    font-family: 'Coming Soon', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', cursive;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CF5C3F;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
}

.body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;
}

.mainHeader img {
    position: relative;
}

.mainHeader img.Logo {
 position: absolute;
 right: 15%;
 top: 74.5%;
 max-width: 20%;
 height: auto;
}

.mainHeader img.Margrit {
 position: absolute;
 right: 15%;
 top: 15%;
 max-width: 20%;
 height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.mainHeader img.Couture {
 position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 5%;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.mainHeader nav {
    background-color: #9cb34f;
 height: 40px;
 margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainFooter {
    position: relative;

    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 
    
    clear: both;
    text-align: left;
    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #9cb34f;
    margin-top: 98%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.mainFooter p {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}


/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
      .body {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 95%;
 }

   .mainHeader img.Margrit {
  right: 5%;
  top: 45%;
 }

   .mainHeader img.Logo {
  right: 5%;
  top: 70%;
 }

   .mainHeader img.Couture {
  top: 20%;
  left: -15%;
 }

   .mainHeader nav {
  height: 160px;
 }

   .mainHeader nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
 }

   .mainHeader nav ul li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 }

   .mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
 }

   .mainFooter {
  width: 100%;
 }
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}


/* ----------- iPad mini ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* ----------- iPad 1 and 2 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}

/* ----------- iPad 3 and 4 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}


/* ----------- Non-Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
}

/* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
  <title>Couture Anni</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body class="body">
  <header class="mainHeader">
   <img class="Logo" src="resources/img/Content%255Cvariation_800_e.png" alt="Logo">
   <img class="Margrit" src="resources/img/IMG_5347_small.jpg" alt="Annamaria Hofstetter">
   <img class="Couture" src="resources/img/Content_variation_800_g.png" alt="Couture Anni">
   
   <nav>
    
    <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
    
      </nav>
  </header>
  
  
        
        <footer class="mainFooter">
            <p>Copyright &copy; <a href="#" title="couture-anni">couture-anni.ch</a></p>
        </footer>
        
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried it on any other mobile devices with success?

Comment: Exactly the same, doesnt apply the changes i made for the respective screen size

Comment: What about on laptops/desktops? Are your media queries working on them?  Which browsers have you tried?

Comment: Maybe it's because you're using `AND` with the `-webkit` settings -- if you're not using a browser that uses those settings, it probably won't return `true` for that condition. Just a guess, but try removing the `-webkit` conditions and see if the media queries work.

Comment: i've tried laptops and i also tried removing the -webkit
both with no success. i also tried different browsers

Comment: All of your media queries are empty, except for the one for `orientation: portrait` between `320px` and `480px`. Are you sure the devices that you expect the media query to apply to fit those characteristics?

Comment: i deleted all empty queries but still no change. nothing gets applied

Comment: What is the pixel size and orientation of the iPhone you're using to test it? When I test your media query on a desktop and change the rule to just `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px)` it applies as it should.

Comment: 320 x 480 the orientation is portrait

Comment: it doesn't apply for me even if i do it exactly like you

Comment: Change your iPhone 4 portrait media rule to this: `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 300px) and (max-device-width: 500px)`.  Does that work?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Are you sure the `link` points to the right place? I saved your snippet above as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/437dkq8c/) and tested it on a Samsung Android phone -- it applies the media rule and shows the menu as it should.  Try it on your iPhone from that jsfiddle link... does it work from there?

Comment: which link do you mean?

Comment: when i use your link with my smartphone it works. But why not in the browser on my pc?

Comment: Your PC doesn't fit that media query, so it won't change at all.

Comment: Thats why im using http://quirktools.com/screenfly/. but no changes are displayed there if i update my website

Comment: If you open the jsfiddle from your desktop and reduce the browser window to under 480px, it doesn't apply the CSS settings change? What browser are you using? It works fine in IE11, so should work in everything else.

Comment: no but if use my iphone it works

Comment: So from QuirkTools, the media query doesn't work on your iPhone, but from jsFiddle, it does?

Comment: You would get better answers and solve your problem easier if you would follow the request for a **minimal** example of the problem: [mcve]

Comment: @freginold yes from jsfiddle it does. and i just realized that it was quirktools that was not displaying my content correctly.

Comment: on my iphone if i enter my website, everything is displayed as i wanted. thank you very kindly for your patience. one last question: if i wanted to know how it looked across different devices as i edited it how would i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/437dkq8c/) of your HTML and CSS; the media query works as it should.  (Tested on a Samsung Android smart phone with default Samsung browser and a desktop PC in IE11.)

If it works for you from the fiddle but not from your QuirkTools page, there may be an issue with that page or with how the CSS is linked there.

Note that the iPhone/portrait query is the only one that will actually change anything -- any devices that don't fit that query (below) will use your default CSS settings.

```
/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
```